# Book references for extensive self study

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Could someone please suggest me a book that can help me to solve the book "Partial Differential equations" by Lawrence C. Evans? Moreover, I need a deep understanding on Sobolev space, Lp-space, Lebesgue integral etc. Please suggest me a good book that would be helpful and easy. Your cooperation in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Folland's [Real Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Real-Analysis-Modern-Techniques-Applications/dp/0471317160) is a pretty standard reference on these topics, although I don't know I would call it "easy".

Comment: Thanks, Jair Taylor for your comment.